# PHP and Nodejs in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I need to configure in the `ProcFile` to work with PHP and JS (nodejs) files.

Apache:PHP through port 80 and Nodejs in other port.

¿Is it possible?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you don't pick the port or the specific web server to use with Heroku apps, and if both projects need to be publicly accessible, you'll likely need to create separate Heroku projects.

Comment: The typical port for apache would be 80... but at the same time running nodejs on another port (any). That's my point

Comment: Right, but (a) Heroku projects run on different ports, and (b) Heroku apps don't use Apache anyway. And (c) a Heroku app only has one public port, so if you need more than one you'll have to set up multiple projects and have them communicate with each other.

Comment: Understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this custom Heroku buildpack: https://github.com/taeram/heroku-buildpack-php-columbo